# How to remove the "edit this entry"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove the following lines

```
<p><?php edit_post_link(__('Edit this entry','express'),''); ?></p>
```

from the rest of the following code:

```
<section class="postmetadata clearfix">
    <?php
        if ( !is_page() && !is_attachment() ) {
            $options = get_option( 'express_theme_options' );

            $time = '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>';
            $categories = get_the_category_list( __(', ', 'express') );
            $tags = get_the_tag_list( __('and tagged ', 'express'),', ' );
            $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
            $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
            $author_link = '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($author_ID) . '">' . $author_name . '</a>';
            $author = sprintf( __( 'by %s', 'express' ), $author_link );
            if ( isset( $options['post-author'] ) && $options['post-author'] ) {
                if ( is_singular() ) {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s on %2$s %3$s %4$s', 'express');
                } elseif ( 'chat' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Filed under %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express' );
                } elseif ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() || 'image' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Displayed in %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express' );
                } else {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express');
                }
            } else {
                if ( is_singular() ) {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s on %2$s %3$s', 'express');
                } elseif ( 'chat' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Filed under %1$s %2$s', 'express' );
                } elseif ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() || 'image' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Displayed in %1$s %2$s', 'express' );
                } else {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s %2$s', 'express');
                }
            }
            if ( is_singular() ) {
                printf( $postmeta, $categories, $time, $tags, $author );
            } else {
                printf( $postmeta, $categories, $tags, $author );
            }
        ?>
        <br />
<?php
if ( comments_open() ) :
  echo '<p>';
   comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &#187;','express'), __('One Comment &#187;','express'), __('% Comments &#187;','express'), __('Comments are closed.', 'express'));
  echo '</p>';
endif;
?>
    <?php } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
        $imagemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
        $time = '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>';
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url();
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
        $parent_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'express' ), esc_attr( $parent_title ) ) . '">' . esc_attr( $parent_title ) . '</a>';
        printf( __( 'Attached to %1$s which was posted on %2$s.' , 'express' ), $parent_link, $time );
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url_raw( $image_url ) . '" title="' . __( 'Link to full-size image.', 'express' ) . '">';
        _e( 'View full image.', 'express' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
    if ( is_singular() || is_page() ) { ?>
        <p><?php edit_post_link(__('Edit this entry','express'),''); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
```

I intend to use the "edit this entry" link at the bottom and the rest of the code right at the top of the page. But when I remove the

```
if ( is_singular() || is_page() ) { ?>
    <p><?php edit_post_link(__('Edit this entry','express'),''); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

my Wordpress page breaks. It should be a syntax error, but I cannot find the right way to separate this part of the code from others.

Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Set the `WP_DEBUG` constant to true on the `wp-config.php` during your dev to see the details of syntax error. And you have to keep the `?>` at the end of the lines you remove

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I'll do that.

Comment: The syntax error is obvious: you remove those lines but _not_ the opening php tag. Therefor the php tags are not balanced any more.

Comment: Just wanted to say I spotted the error through WP_DEBUG. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally deleted some tags that have to stay.

`if ( is_singular() || is_page() ) { ?>` <- this one has to stay

Try this:

```
<section class="postmetadata clearfix">
    <?php
        if ( !is_page() && !is_attachment() ) {
            $options = get_option( 'express_theme_options' );

            $time = '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>';
            $categories = get_the_category_list( __(', ', 'express') );
            $tags = get_the_tag_list( __('and tagged ', 'express'),', ' );
            $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
            $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
            $author_link = '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($author_ID) . '">' . $author_name . '</a>';
            $author = sprintf( __( 'by %s', 'express' ), $author_link );
            if ( isset( $options['post-author'] ) && $options['post-author'] ) {
                if ( is_singular() ) {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s on %2$s %3$s %4$s', 'express');
                } elseif ( 'chat' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Filed under %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express' );
                } elseif ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() || 'image' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Displayed in %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express' );
                } else {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s %2$s %3$s', 'express');
                }
            } else {
                if ( is_singular() ) {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s on %2$s %3$s', 'express');
                } elseif ( 'chat' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Filed under %1$s %2$s', 'express' );
                } elseif ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() || 'image' == get_post_format() ) {
                    $postmeta = __( 'Displayed in %1$s %2$s', 'express' );
                } else {
                    $postmeta = __('Posted in %1$s %2$s', 'express');
                }
            }
            if ( is_singular() ) {
                printf( $postmeta, $categories, $time, $tags, $author );
            } else {
                printf( $postmeta, $categories, $tags, $author );
            }
        ?>
        <br />
<?php
if ( comments_open() ) :
  echo '<p>';
   comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &#187;','express'), __('One Comment &#187;','express'), __('% Comments &#187;','express'), __('Comments are closed.', 'express'));
  echo '</p>';
endif;
?>
    <?php } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
        $imagemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
        $time = '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>';
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url();
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
        $parent_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'express' ), esc_attr( $parent_title ) ) . '">' . esc_attr( $parent_title ) . '</a>';
        printf( __( 'Attached to %1$s which was posted on %2$s.' , 'express' ), $parent_link, $time );
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url_raw( $image_url ) . '" title="' . __( 'Link to full-size image.', 'express' ) . '">';
        _e( 'View full image.', 'express' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
    ?>
</section>
```